# Tooltip issue on columnrange highchart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

[image]

Thi picture shows a columnrange dataRange . xAxsis shows date and yAxsis shows hours but it is `inverted :false`. I am trying to format tooltip by updating the values like '1,2622,349.. ' as appear on tooltip . I couldn't find where this values comes from .

This is my yAxis

```
 yAxis: {

                type: 'datetime',
                labels: {
                    formatter: function () {
                        return Highcharts.dateFormat('%H:%M:%P', this.value);
                    }
                },

                title: {
                    text: 'Y Sside New'
                }
            },
```

Can anyone tell me where should I look in the chart to figure out this issue ?

Thanks

Comment: What are you asking? What do you want it to look like? What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`tooltip.formatter`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.formatter). Just write something which will change timestamps to string dates (like you did for `yAxis.labels.formatter`).